# What is the command for "Select All" in Vim and VsVim?

Tags: key-bindings

How do I select all the content of a file in Vim and VsVim? Like in other editors <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> does the job for select all.

Comment: SibiCoder's answer is good, but it would be useful to know what you intend to do with the content you copied.

Comment: First, you "select" some text in a "buffer", not in a "file". Two, "selecting" is often useless in Vim so you must be clear about what you want to do with that "selection". For you and for us.

Comment: @romainly I think the OP means selecting the whole file in visual mode, considering that `ctrl+a` in other editors visually highlights the entire file.

Comment: @statox Why did you edit [tag:vsvim] out? It's not a huge deal to me, but I think the tag is perfectly appropriate, and I didn't want to get in an edit war. (I would have pinged you in `:chat!`, but you haven't been in that room recently, so it wouldn't let me)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem: It was an error: I first thought that `vsvim` was like `vimperator` and this kind of plugins for other softwares and thus was off topic so I removed it, then I had a doubt so I checked meta and [saw that it was on topic](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/37/1841) so I approved your tag edit but forgot to edit the question again. I'm changing that right now, sorry for that.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`ggVG` selects all content. `gg` moves to first line. `V` starts visual mode. `G` jumps to last line thereby selecting from first to last line

Comment: I keep getting no a vim command for ggVG  and gg, even G

Comment: Both mine and yours are correct. Visual mode works both ways

Comment: It may be unnecessary to capitalize the 'V' here, since the "whole line" part seems moot because the two boundaries are at the very beginning and the very end of the file.

Answer (score 47):

Along with SibiCoder's answer, if you have a clear idea of what you want to do you can use the following:

```
:%X
```

Where `X` is a command, for example:

```
:%d             -> delete every line
:%y             -> yank every line
:%normal! >>    -> indent every line
```

You have also the global command `:g` which, with the search pattern `^`, can do the same thing:

```
:g/^/d             -> delete every line
:g/^/y             -> yank every line
:g/^/normal! >>    -> indent every line
```

If what you want is selecting the text, then `ggVG` is fine, but keep in mind these method, in the case you already know what is the next step. Note that it won't leave the cursor in visual mode.

See: `:h :%` and `:h :g` for reference.

---

Note that, even though the `C-A` mapping is used in vim (see `:h CTRL-A`), you can map it to do what other editors do:

```
nnoremap <C-A> ggVG
```

Just be aware that mapping `C-A` could clash with other plugins' mappings or with `screen`'s default prefix.

Comment: Note that `:>` is an Ex command, so `:%>` works

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are good. Here's another alternative.

Since you mention that you are using VsVim, you can change which keys are handled by visual Studio, and which keys are handled by vsvim. Go to

> Tools -> Options -> VsVim -> Keyboard

From there you can set Ctrl-a to be handled by Visual Studio, rather than VsVim.

Although I do not recommend this since you will not be able to use vim's `<C-a>`, which I find to be an essential feature. Though it's up to you.

Answer (score 5):

As @SibiCoder mentioned `ggVG` does the trick, but I like something closer to `Ctrl+A`.

So I added this line to my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <leader>a ggVG
```

Now pressing `<leader>a` will select everything, in my case it's `\a`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Theoretically you could map control a (`<C-a>`), but it happens to have a useful default functionality

Comment: Yeah, that's why I prefer `<leader>a`

Comment: to know what `<leader>` is : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764336/10204932

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a faster/more intuitive way to do this and don't mind adding a plugin, this looks handy: https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-entire

Answer (score 1):

I used to use `map <leader>a ggVG` to select all, but later I found that [`Cmd+V`/`Ctrl+V` pasting has an extra new line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/41520/36863). So nowadays, I use:

```
map <leader>a G$vgg0
```

Which works without side effects.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the carriage return issue with the Visual Line mode. Also, your your suggested mapping could be just `<Leader>a ggv$G$`

Comment: @ranemirusG Thanks for the suggestion, edited.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a big number like **99999yy** to select all the content of your file

Comment: Files larger than `100000` lines are possible, though rare. Also, using `yy` will *yank* them, not *select* them.

Comment: yah sure you are right but when selecting something it's for the most cases to cut,copy or delete them :)

Comment: That's what i needed. Select all and yank.

Comment: Just `:%y`  is enough. Or `:%y +` to yank everything in the `+` register.

Answer (score 0):

`:1` puts your cursor at the beginning of the 1st line.  Then `VG` selects everything.

Then you do whatever you want with the selection: yank, delect, copy, ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit-->SelectAll from toolbar

Comment: Works in GUI mode. You will notice that behind "SelectAll" it says `ggVG`. Many experienced vi users will find it cumbersome to take their hands of their keyboards ;)