# `Cmd+V`/`Ctrl+V` pasting has an extra new line

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, cut-copy-paste

In `init.vim` I have the following setting to ensure the text is yanked to the system clipboard:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

In Neovim, I select the lines with visual line mode (`V`) and copy them with `y`:

```
a
b
c
```

In a webpage textarea, do <kbd>Cmd+V</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, what's being pasted is:

```
a
b
c
   an extra new line
```

I don't want the extra line when pasting. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [Vivian's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/41521/36863), I rewrote the visual line mode with:

```
map V 0v$
map Vk $v0k
```

Which doesn't have the extra line caused by the original visual line mode.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the line mode selection (`V`) the yank (`y`) operation will yank the carriage return at the end of the line.

If you don't want the carriage return at end of the last line you have to use the normal selection mode (`v`)

- On the first line use `0` to go to the start of the line
- On the last line use `g_` (instead of `$`) to go to the end of the line

Comment: Oh god, you can't imagine how long this issue has bugged me, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) You are welcome ;-)